# Unexpected output from if/elif structures

Tags: python, if-statement

I got some if/elif structures. I have no errors when it runs, but the 3 outputs are the same (they should not be). I can not really see, what is the cause of this problem.

The concerned part of my code: (RGB_l is a 1 by 3 matrix, I create a variable for each of its component and apply an if/elif structure, to decide which calculation needs to be done).

```
    X = float(input("X: "))/100
    Y = float(input("Y: "))/100
    Z = float(input("Z: "))/100

    b = np.array([[X],
                  [Y],
                  [Z]])
    a = np.array([[3.2406, -1.5372, -0.4986],
                  [-0.9689, 1.8758, 0.0415],
                  [0.0557, -0.2040, 1.057]])

    RGB_l = np.dot(a, b)
    print("RGB linear :", RGB_l)

    R_l = RGB_l[0, 0]
    G_l = RGB_l[1, 0]
    B_l = RGB_l[2, 0]

    a = 0.055

    if R_l <= 0.0031308:
        R = 12.92*R_l
    elif R_l > 0.0031308:
        R = ((1+a)**(1/2.4))-a
    print(R)

    if G_l <= 0.0031308:
        G = 12.92*G_l
    elif G_l > 0.0031308:
        G = ((1+a)**(1/2.4))-a
    print(G)

    if B_l <= 0.0031308:
        B = 12.92*B_l
    elif B_l > 0.0031308:
        B = ((1+a)**(1/2.4))-a
    print(B)
```

Outputs for R, G and B are :

```
0.967559351663262
0.967559351663262
0.967559351663262
```

Could you help me to fix my code? Thanks

Comment: It would help if you showed the contents of `RGB_l`.

Comment: Sure I just edit the post

Comment: Whats the result of ```print("RGB linear :", RGB_l)``` ? seems like each of your slices is the same number.

Comment: The result is `RGB linear : [[0.24856608]
 [0.21582176]
 [0.49319549]]`

Comment: What are your X,Y,Z values? I've used 100, 2, 30 and got different R,G,B values... If X,Y,Z are close to each other then R,G,B are almost always the same.

Comment: Also, what's the point in using `elif` instead of simple `else` if you compare to the same value?

Comment: In this example I used : X = 26.87, Y=24.28 and Z=49.93

Comment: Yes good remark for the `else` thing I'll change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values you have are greater than `0.0031308`

and so the print statement for each is `((1+a)**(1/2.4))-a`

the actual value in the array isn't part of the output.

Comment: Holy Moly how could I not see this ! Thank you it should work now

Comment: ha!, took me a second to see it too. Good luck!